# pytz module ImportError : how to configure pytz module in eclipse(pydev)?

Tags: python, eclipse, pytz

My computer : Mac OSX 10.9.4
IDE : Eclipse(kelper) + pydev + Django 1.5 + python 2.7

I download pytz module on my python by typing code below on terminal :

```
easy_install --upgrade pytz
```

And I also download the pytz module by django like below :

```
$ sudo pip install pytz
```

And I right-click on project and preceded to properties - pydev(-interpreter/grammar) - PYTHONPATH.

and new folders to  System PYTHONPATH and those were below :

```
1. System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pytz
2. System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
3. Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.4-py2.7.egg
4. Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.4-py2.7.egg/pytz
```

But whenever I run project it made error below :

```
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

On eclipse/Pydev it doesn't display any error icons(like red x, or yello warning button) and
also can import pytz module on pydev shell environment..

ha.. seriously this is driving me crazy..

I also restart eclipse and pydev disconnect/connection but doesn't not work..

How could I resolve this problem? I need help :( ...

Comment: You might have multiple `python` executables on your system. Check `python -c'import sys; print("\n".join(sys.path))`. The *parent* of `pytz` directory (a directory with `__init__.py` file) should be in it.

Comment: Most likely here is [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30224806/204814) you are looking for.