# pytz install on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, pytz

Django informs me "ImportError: No module named pytz", but when I go to use pip to install it, I get this result:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
```

Is it possible that it is looking in the wrong location, or that I need to try to install it somewhere else?

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
Internal Server Error: /basicloginwebservice/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 103, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 321, in resolve
    sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 223, in resolve
    return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 230, in callback
    self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 29, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 97, in get_callable
    mod = import_module(mod_name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/<redacted>/django/<redacted>/<redacted>/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras` is a location associated with the Apple-supplied Python 2.7 (`/usr/bin/python2.7`).  It's not possible to tell from the traceback but chances are that Django is being run under a different instance of Python 2.7, perhaps linked to from `/usr/local/bin`.  These sorts of problems can arise when there are multiple instances of Python and you are using `pip` directly from the command line.  Make sure you have a version of `pip` installed for each Python you are using.  And, to ensure that you are using the right instance of `pip`, you can invoke it this way:

`python -m pip install pytz`

substituting for `python` the same path that is used to run Django.

Another approach is to always use an activated `virtualenv` which should ensure that the right `python` and `pip` instances are found first on the process `PATH`.